# Looking for an efficient way to store history data

Tags: python, storage

The data is a python dict representing a state of something that changes slowly over the time. Values change often, usually one or two items at a time. The keys can change too, but that's a rare event. After each change the new data set is remembered for future examination.

The result is a long sequence with increasing timestamps. A very simple example of "b" turned on and off and on again:

```
(timestamp1, {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':False}),
(timestamp2, {'a':False, 'b':True, 'c':False}),
(timestamp3, {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':False}), 
(timestamp4, {'a':False, 'b':True, 'c':False}),
```

This sequence is very convenient to work with, but obviously quite inefficient. Almost the same data is copied over and over. The real dict has about 100 items. That's why I'm looking for a different way to store the data history both in memory and on a disk.

I'm pretty sure this has been addressed many times in the past. **Is there any standard/recommended way for this problem?** The solution doesn't have to be perfect. Good enough is good enough.

---

This is what I would do unless some kind soul shows a better approach. Storing just incremental changes is space efficient:

```
(timestamp1, FULL, {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':False}),
(timestamp2, INCREMENTAL, {'b':True}),
(timestamp3, INCREMENTAL, {'b':False}),
(timestamp4, INCREMENTAL, {'b':True}),
```

However the data is not easy to access, because it must be restored in several steps from last FULL state. To limit the drawback, every N-th record will be stored as FULL, all others as INCREMENTAL.

I would probably add this small improvement: adding a reference to the same state already recorded in order to prevent duplication:

```
(timestamp1, FULL, {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':False}),
(timestamp2, INCREMENTAL, {'b':True}),
(timestamp3, SAME_AS, timestamp1),
(timestamp4, SAME_AS, timestamp2),
```

Comment: I was going to suggest what you describe as the incremental approach. Excited to see some more ideas. I'll comment back if I think of anything.

**Edit**: can you briefly describe the application?

Comment: @jphollowed: this particular application is for home automation. Switches, lights, blinds, temperatures, ventilation, some valves etc.

Answer (score 4):

A more space-efficient approach is to keep a set for each "column" of data. That is, we keep a set for columns `a`, `b`, and `c`. The set keeps track of the timestamps for which the column's value is `True`. For instance, for the data:

```
(timestamp1, {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':False}),
(timestamp2, {'a':False, 'b':True, 'c':False}),
(timestamp3, {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':False}), 
(timestamp4, {'a':False, 'b':True, 'c':False}),
```

the set for column `a` will be empty, the set for column `b` will contain timestamps 2 and 4, and the set for column `c` will again be empty.

Note that this is more-or-less the approach one might take to store a sparse binary vector. Rather than store the entire vector, we just keep track of where the vector is 1. In fact, you might want to consider using a sparse matrix data type from [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Sets offer efficient (constant time) membership lookup, so this is also a time-efficient way of doing this.

To make the data easy to access you can write a small class which wraps the sets. For example:

```
class SparseStates(object):

    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.data = {col: set() for col in columns}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        row, column = key
        return row in self.data[column]

    def turn_on(self, row, column):
        self.data[column].add(row)
```

Usage:

```
>>> states = SparseStates(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> states.turn_on(2, 'b')
>>> states.turn_on(4, 'b')
>>> states[2, 'a']
False
>>> states[2, 'b']
True
>>> states.data['a']
{}
>>> states.data['b']
{2, 4}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing a "column oriented" thinking. Browsing/searching might benefit from it.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer and I would accept it as a suggestion for in-memory storage format. However to store the data on a disk I have to retain the sequence structure where new records are appended.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at PeopleSoft's EFFDT system for inspiration.  It's intended for storage and querying with a database, but the principles remain.

Each item is stored separately, with a key, a time-of-effect (EFFDT) and the various values.

So, taking 'a' and 'b', you would have this type of storage:

```
KEY     EFFDT       Active  VALUES
a       2016-07-16  True    False
a       2016-03-20  True    True
a       2016-01-16  True    False

        #note that 2016-11-22 is a future date.  its data will "activate"
        #any time your selection date criteria is >= Nov 22
b       2016-11-22  False   True

b       2016-05-16  True    False
b       2016-01-16  True    True
```

A database lookup for A and B, today, goes:

```
select * from storage 
where KEY in ('A','B') 
and EFFDT = 
    /* pick the last date that is before the limit date (today */
    (select MAX(EFFDT) 
    from storage sub 
    where sub.key = storage.key
    and   sub.effdt <= '2016-07-19'
    )
```

You basically have to think of EFFDT as "boundaries to the ranges of time when the data has a certain value".  The Active column enables you to delete a key logically, by setting it to False.

You might store the above in a compound object, with your keys and then a a sorted list of dates.  A lookup would then consist of finding the key, then the latest date matching your criteria.

```
{
    #key    timestamp     active values.
    "a" : [("2016-07-16", True, (True,)),
           ("2016-03-20", True, (False,)),
           ("2016-01-16", True, (True,),
          },
    "b" : [("2016-05-16", True, (False,)),
           ("2016-01-16", True, (True,)),
          ],
}
```

Note:  I have added Active because this what makes this system a general-purpose historical storage qualifier.  But in your case, you wouldn't be interested in it.

A lookup of all the keys still active as of 2016-12-24 would only return 'a' : (False) and would like this in SQL:

```
select * from storage 
where Active = True   /* dont want Active=False data so 
                         we filter the subquery results.*/
and EFFDT = 
    /* pick the last date that is before the limit date (today */
    (select MAX(EFFDT) 
    from storage sub 
    where sub.key = storage.key
    and   sub.effdt <= '2016-12-24'
    )
```

Comment: It took me some time to think about it, but I find the idea "store each item separately" helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pickle to store the dictionary content depending on the timestamp. You simply generate pickled files with the timestamp as their name. You can also compress the files using pickle. Pickle should be implemented in a way that you won't easily be able to compress the content any better manually.

If you want to make sure that two equal configurations of your dictionary are stored in the same pickled file, you can additionally compute a hash value over the string representation of the dictionary.